# Non-dense subspace implies non-zero measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, continuity, topological-vector-spaces, nets

I am reading a proof of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem by De Branges, but I am having trouble understanding the following part.

Let $E$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $C_0(E, \mathbb{C})$ the continuous functions vanishing at infinity. For a vector subspace $S \subset C_0(E, \mathbb{C})$, define the set $M(S)$ of all signed measures $\mu$ on $E$ satisfying the following two properties: $\mu$ has a total variation of at most 1 and for all $f \in S$ we have $\int f \, d\mu = 0$. Equip $M(S)$ with the weak-*topology. Then if $S$ is not dense in $C_0(E, \mathbb{C})$, then $M(S)$ contains a non-zero measure.

I have tried the following. Since $S$ is not dense in $C_0(E, \mathbb{C})$, there exists a function that cannot be approximated by a net. I have tried constructing a measure from this function that satisfies the conditions of $M(S)$, but I did not manage to succeed. Also I tried, arguing by contraposition, showing that if $M(S)$ consists only of the zero measure, then $S$ would be dense in $C_0(E, \mathbb{C})$. For this I would have to show that any function in $C_0(E, \mathbb{C})$ is the limit of some net. However, I failed here also. Perhaps, I could use the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem?

I have no clue on how to show this. Does anyone have a hint? Thank you very much :)

Comment: This is just the Hahn-Banach theorem (plus the Riesz Representation Theorem).

Comment: I am quite new to the theory. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If $X$ is a Banach space then $X^*$ is the "dual space", the space of bounded linear maps $\Lambda:X\to K$, where $K$ is the scalar field. A hugely important result, Hahn-Banach, says in part that if $S$ is a non-dense subspace of $X$ then there exists $\Lambda\in X^*$ with $\Lambda\ne0$ but $\Lambda|_S=0$. Now if $X=C_0(E)$ as above then the Riesz Representation Theorem says that there exists a complex Borel measure $\mu$ such that $\Lambda f=\int f\,d\mu$ for all $f$, and $||\mu||=||\Lambda||>0$.

Comment: Indeed, from this it follows quite easiliy. However, I recall only from the Hahn-Banach that we can separate. That is, there exists a functional $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(f) > \varphi(g)$ for all $f\in S^c$ and $g\in S$.

Comment: Luckily there are ways to find results that you don't recall. See the second paragraph in the section "Applications": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem

Comment: btw: If $S$ is a subspace of $X$, $f\in X\setminus S$, $\phi\in X^*$ and $\phi(f)>\phi(g)$ for all $g\in S$ then $\phi|_S=0$. Because if $\phi|_S\ne 0$ it's clear that $\sup_{g\in S}\phi(g)=+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks very much!